# Bash's "alias" command and .bashrc contents differ

Tags: java, bash, alias

I added an alias to `~/.bashrc` like below:

`alias jetty_home=”java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar”`

If I try to execute `source ~/.bashrc` it prints

```
alias: -jar: not found  
alias: /path/to/libexec/start.jar": not found
```

When I call `alias` the output is:
`alias jetty_home='"java'`

and for `jetty_home` the output is:
`"java: command not found`

Obviously I'm messing up with spaces and escaping here. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: In the alias definition you've posted, the quotes aren't standard double-quotes, is it a copy/paste problem or are those the original quotes? If they are, you need to change those to standard quotes (either simple or double would work here)

Comment: Note that in general, aliases shouldn't be used regardless -- functions are preferred in almost every case.

Comment: `jetty_home() { java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar "$@"; }` -- the equivalent function -- doesn't require quotes around it at all, so moots the whole problem.

Comment: geez, that was it. I wouldn't have spotted it in a million years! Thanks @Aaron

Comment: Now I'm having trouble reloading the contents. I corrected the quotes (and tried the function as well), but when calling `source` it still gives me the old errors. Do I need to logout and in again?

Comment: So, for the function definitely you want to `unalias jetty_home` before sourcing the updated file so the existing alias doesn't break the function declaration (by changing it to `”java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar”() { java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar "$@"; }`), or just start a new shell session that never had the old alias in the first place. For the alias not working, that's more interesting. Consider reading the output of a trace log: `PS4='${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+' bash -xli` will start a new shell and log what it's doing during startup

Comment: sorry, I'm probably doing something stupid but I tried `unalias jetty_home`, updated `.bashrc` contents to `jetty_home() { java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar "$@"; }`, and when trying to `source ~/.bashrc` it still gives me `-jar: not found` and `path/to/...: not found`. The quotes in the error message are still the wrong ones so I'm guessing it's getting this from some temporary file somewhere but I'm obviously no expert

Comment: `$ cat .bashrc`jetty_home() { java -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jetty/9.4.40.v20210413/libexec/start.jar "$@"; }
`$ source ~/.bashrc`
-bash: alias: -jar: not found
-bash: alias: /usr/Cellar/9.4.40.v20210413/libexec/start.jar”: not found

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the alias out with `alias jetty_home='java -jar ~/path/to/libexec/start.jar'`

Comment: This is a typo fix (`”` vs `"` being a typographic issue in nature). Problems caused by typos should be closed with a comment, not answered -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and its link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- which has "questions about problems caused by typographic errors" as #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list.